# 550 Cannot receive from specified address

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I followed all the instructions on heroku and sendgrid but users receive an error when they try to sign up.
I ran the logs and here is the error.
What is wrong here?

```
2013-07-01 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Cannot receive from specified address <jay.mancho1@gmail.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

my settings;

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.mailer_sender = "jay.mancho1@gmail.com"
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '***.herokuapp.com' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['***@heroku.com'],
  :password       => ENV['***'],
  :domain         => ENV['heroku.com']
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the line where you are setting the username and password to be `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']`, not your actual password. These values are stored on the server and should not appear in your code.